# Should average response time include failed transactions or not?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

In loadrunner report it excludes failed transactions for calculating average response time but in JMeter it includes failed transactions as well for calculating average response time. I am bit confused here. What is the best way to calculate average response time? Should it include failed transactions or not? Detailed explanations will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where exactly your "transaction" failed.

If it reached the server, made a "hit" (or several hits), kicked off request processing and failed with non-successful status code - I believe it should be included as your load testing tool has triggered the request and it's the application under test which failed to respond properly or on time.

If the "transaction" didn't start due to missing test data or incorrect configuration of the load testing tool - it shouldn't be included. However it means that your test is not correct and needs to be fixed.

So for well-behaved tests I would **include everything** into the report and maybe prepared 3 views:

1. Everything (with passed and failed transactions)
2. Successes only
3. Failures only

In JMeter you can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to remove failed transactions from the final report, the tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Answer (score 0):

A failed transaction can be faster than one which passes.   Example, a 4xx or 5xx status message may arrive almost instantaneously back to the client.   Get enough of these errors and your average response time will drop considerably.  In fact, if I was an unscrupulous tester, castigated for the level of failure on my tests, I might include a lot of "fast responses" in my data set to deliberately skew the response time so my stakeholders don't yell at me anymore.

Not that this every happens.

Comment: Most of 5xx status are not faster than 2xx responses in my application.

Comment: Didn't you just make the same argument, but with the skew on response time in the opposite direction for why you may want to exclude response times for failure from your data set.   Still report the failure....just not the time associated with it by default